# Get J1 visa after not filing tax return on previous J1 visa

Tags: immigration, taxes, j-visa

In the summer of 2018 I did an internship in the US on a J1 visa. I didn't realise I needed to file my tax returns with the IRS. I don't owe them any money though because of a tax treaty with the UK.

Now I'm going for another internship and need to apply for a J1 visa again. Chatting with a friend, I realised my situation with the taxes. I have sent all the paperwork to the IRS but I'm not sure it will be processed before I have my visa interview at the embassy.

Do you think this will be an issue? I've read that the USCIS (immigration folks) and IRS do not cross-check databases.